# Idea gui programming (in form)

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm trying to do a nice GUI form in intellij. I'm using gridLayoutManager(intellij). Is possible to do something like this?

```
                  |
           Button | Buttton
                  |
                  |
                  |
          ________|________
          Here comboBox
```

Comment: it is hard to understand your question, could you describe what you want to get?

Comment: Sorry for not picture, but i have't enought respect for this. I want divide screen on half vertically and half horizontally. Then up on horizontally line i want to have in two columns two buttons, and under i want have on column and one combobox

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what you exactly expect, but you can try something like this for example:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,combo);
```

You can use GridLayout in Panel, and add it into frames BorderLayout. But you can also use only GridLayouts:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    innerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    innerPanel.add(button1);
    innerPanel.add(button2);
    panel.add(innerPanel);
    panel.add(combo);
```

Here you use one panel with GridLayout, within another panel with GridLayout. Effect should be the same.
However those are not most elegant ways to do that. It would be better if you would learn to use GridBagLayout (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). It is much more flexible layout.